# How to fix NumPy dotting errors due to 0 dimensional matrices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, neural-network

While building a neural network and trying to compute the derivative of my cost with respect to my weights, I encounter this error when trying to dot product my matrices.

> ValueError: shapes (3,) and (1,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)

My Code:
(The part that is probably most important is the function Backpropagation)

```
import numpy as np

class Feedforward:


def __init__(self, size_vector):

    self.nLayers = len(size_vector)
    weight_matrix = lambda x: np.random.random((x[0],x[1]))
    self.weights = {}
    self.b = {}
    self.z = {}
    self.a = {}

    for i in range(0,self.nLayers,1):
        z = size_vector[i:i+2]
        try:
            self.b[i] = np.random.random(size_vector[i+1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
        if len(z) == 2:
            self.weights[i] = weight_matrix(z)


def activation(self, matrix):
    return (np.exp(2*matrix)-1)/(np.exp(2*matrix)+1)

def activation_prime(self, matrix):
    return 1/(1-np.square(matrix))


def f_pass(self, data):
    for layer in range(self.nLayers-1):
        if layer == 0:
            self.z[layer] = data.dot(self.weights[0])+self.b[layer]
            self.a[layer] = self.activation(self.z[layer])
        else:
            self.z[layer] = self.a[layer-1].dot(self.weights[layer])+self.b[layer]
            self.a[layer] = self.activation(self.z[layer])

def backporpagate(self, expected):
    cost = np.square(expected-self.a[self.nLayers-2])
    partial_layer_error = {}
    partial_weight_error = {}
    partial_bias_error = {}
    for i in range(self.nLayers-1):
        layer = self.nLayers-2-i
        if i == 0:
            partial_layer_error[layer] = 2*np.power(cost, .5)*self.activation_prime(self.z[layer])
            partial_weight_error[layer] = self.a[layer-1].transpose().dot(partial_layer_error[layer])
            partial_bias_error[layer] = partial_layer_error[layer]
        elif layer == 0:
            partial_layer_error[layer] = partial_layer_error[layer+1].dot(self.weights[layer+1].transpose())
            partial_weight_error[layer] = self.a[layer].dot(partial_layer_error[layer])
            partial_bias_error[layer] = partial_layer_error[layer]
        else:
            partial_layer_error[layer] = partial_layer_error[layer+1].dot(self.weights[layer+1].transpose())
            partial_weight_error[layer] = self.a[layer].dot(partial_layer_error[layer])
            partial_bias_error[layer] = partial_layer_error[layer]

    print('NN Layer Costs are: \n')
    print(partial_layer_error)
    print('NN Bias Costs are: \n')
    print(partial_bias_error)
    print('NN Weight Costs are: \n')
    print(partial_weight_error)

with open('mnist_test.csv') as f:
data = f.readlines()
mnist = []
for i in data:
    key = i[0]
    value = i[1:]
    value = value.replace('\n','')
    value = value.split(',')
    value.pop(0)
    value = [int(x) for x in value]
    mnist.append((key,value))

N = Feedforward([2,3,1])
print('NN Weights are: \n')
print(N.weights)
print('NN Biases are: \n')
print(N.b)
N.f_pass(np.array([1,2]))
print('NN Summations are: \n')
print(N.z)
print('NN Activations are: \n')
print(N.a)
N.backporpagate(np.array([1]))
```

I will paste the output of my terminal here so you can see the results and shapes of the matrices

> NN Weights are:
>
> {0: array([[ 0.92603489,  0.43665109,  0.99003931],
>          [ 0.8336553 ,  0.78370378,  0.45612777]]), 1: array([[ 0.75876672],
>          [ 0.08175101],
>          [ 0.1875789 ]])} NN Biases are:
>
> {0: array([ 0.47764224,  0.43533307,  0.44388977]), 1: array([
>   0.03250969])} NN Summations are:
>
> {0: array([ 3.07098773,  2.43939172,  2.34618461]), 1: array([
>   1.05270827])} NN Activations are:
>
> {0: array([ 0.99570789,  0.98490231,  0.98183657]), 1: array([
>   0.78285705])} Traceback (most recent call last):   File "Neural Network (Backprop).py", line 91, in 
>       N.backporpagate(np.array([1]))   File "Neural Network (Backprop).py", line 50, in backporpagate
>       partial_weight_error[layer] = self.a[layer-1].transpose().dot(partial_layer_error[layer])
>   ValueError: shapes (3,) and (1,) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 1 (dim 0)

But as you can see, activatio0 is a 1x3 matrix and partial_layer_error 1 is a 1x1 matrix. So activation0 transpose dot partial error should work. But instead I get the ShapeError

Comment: The error says the shapes are (3,) and (1,) not (1,3) and (1,1).  In numpy there's a difference.  The rule for `dot` is that the last dimension on A must match the 2nd to the last (or only) dimension of B.  3 does not match 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`activation0` is a [rank-1 array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/quickstart.html#the-basics). It's shape is (3,) and the shape of it's transpose is also (3,). You may want to add a second dimension to your array. Some useful methods are:

- [`activation0[:,None]` or `activation0[:,np.newaxis]`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)
- [`np.reshape(activation0, (-1, 1))`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html)
- [`np.expand_dims(activation0, axis=1)`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)

Comment: Thank you, I added .reshape((m,n)) after each computation to force each matrix to the expected size. All works